# Creating a dynamic quiz page with spring mvc/jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I need to make a page that would show quiz questions and answers and pressing next you would move to another question. However the only way I managed is just passing a list of questions and displaying them all.

What I have is:

```
    <form:form action="/new" method="POST" modelAttribute="answer">
        <c:forEach varStatus="count" var="tempCustomer" items="${questions}">
            <p class="question">${count.count}. ${tempCustomer.question}</p>
            <c:forEach var="tempAnswer" varStatus="vs" items="${tempCustomer.questionAnswerList}">
                <ul class="answers">

                    <form:checkbox  path="answers[${count.index}].answer_id" value="${tempAnswer.question_id}"/>${tempAnswer.answerText}

                </ul>
            </c:forEach>
            <form:hidden path="answers[${count.index}].question_id" value="${tempCustomer.question_id}"/>

        </c:forEach>
```

This returns a list of questions on the page like so:
[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/varzH.jpg)

What I want to do is have a form that you can click next on for each question. I've been trying to figure this out for days now. So any pointers to the right direction would be appreciated. I can't find any info on how to do this kind of form with spring.

Comment: Can you show me the controller that handles "/new" endpoint

Comment: The controller just prints out the choices that were made. What I want to do is make the questions appear one by one. And I am struggling on finding a way to do it.

Comment: What about you map the question to an index. All questions are stored in a linkedHashMap to respect the order.

{
  1: "What is an apple?"
}

The controller just receives the next index, and it returns the question which has the index?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do that. Is there something I could search for to help me understand how to do that? I'm pretty new to this you see.